# My code was running in console but not in tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I was practising coding using JavaScript in console. it works, but there is a problem in Tampermonkey

```
function name() {
  var console = document.querySelector('.className');
  let magic = console.childNodes;
  magic[0].innerHTML = '23213';
};
name();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you expand your question to include what problem you are experiencing, any error messages you're getting, how you're running it and what you want it to do exactly. On SO we call this a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

make sure the line

```
// @match http://example.com/
```

is match your target URL

`.childNodes` return `text` and `tagname` so you can't always use `.innerHTML`, use `.children` instead.

Please don't use `console` as variable because it browser variable to output log in your browser

example working script for `http://example.com`

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         example Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  go to http://example.com/ and see the result
// @author       You
// @match        http://example.com/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function name() {
    var div = document.querySelector('div');
    let magic = div.children;
    magic[0].innerHTML = '23213';
    console.log('success!');
};
name();
```